# stm32 programming stm32 or beaglebone

Tags: stm32, beaglebone-black

I would like to program stm32f4 or possibly others from beaglebone (black) board.

Is it possible to load firmware over serial (uart) or somehow to the stm32?
Is it possible to use two stm32 , one for development other one for loading new firmware?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you *only* want to load a program to an STM32F4 from a BeagleBone Black? Or have you access to a Windows platform? What do you mean by "or possibly others"? Do you mean other STM32F MCUs, or Cortex-M parts from other manufacturers (not ST Micro) or something even more general?

Comment: I thought about STM32 to STM32 in first, but if there is like serial interface that could be emulated other MCU would also be option. In that sense only MCU to MCU (or beaglebone) was intended to be used.

Comment: Okay, understood. IMHO @Arsenal has covered the basic options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ST-Link is basically just a STM32F103 which will interface to the PC on one side and the MCU under development on the other side and download new code to it.

I haven't seen a firmware or source code available to build your own ST-Link, so I guess it's still closed. But considering that a Nucleo Board contains a ST-Link and costs only 10 bucks, it's maybe not worth the trouble to build one on your own. There are some tries to get a linux driver for a ST-Link [here](https://github.com/texane/stlink).

The internal bootloader on the STM32F4 is quite flexible and allows different interfaces to be used. There are specifications for each of the protocols available:

- [AN3155 - USART](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00264342.pdf)
- [AN3156 - USB DFU](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00264379.pdf)
- [AN4221 - I2C](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00072315.pdf)
- [AN4286 - SPI](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00081379.pdf)

There are [different ways](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00167594.pdf#page=18) to get into the bootloader, depending on which chip you use and other boundaries.

One of the easier ways to get there is to pull the BOOT0 pin high and reset the device. Then it boots into the bootloader and the before mentioned protocols are available.

For windows there is a GUI and command line tool available under the name [STSW-MCU005 Flash loader demonstrator](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1533/PF257525?s_searchtype=keyword). That thing comes with source code, so probably you are able to port it to Linux and make it run on your beaglebone. That way it might be possible to skip fully understanding all the protocol details (though that never hurts).

The JTAG protocol is (as far as I know) not freely available, so implementing your own JTAG flasher would require you getting a copy of the IEEE 1149.1 and going on from there. Another option is to get a copy of the [ARM Debug Interface Architecture Specification](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0031c/index.html) (available for free upon registration with ARM). I haven't looked into it in detail, but it seems to describe the debug capabilities of the ARM cores in great detail. So that might be a better starting point than the IEEE standard.

I don't know if ST has some extensions on the JTAG/SWD protocol, some vendors do this.

That said your best bet is probably the internal bootloader if you want to get results faster. As long as you don't program your controller in a way so that it is no longer accessible.

Comment: The JTAG protocol is fully standardized; it's just nontrivial to use it to program a device. (I believe it amounts to poking the flash control registers over JTAG.)

Comment: @duskwuff just because something is fully standardizes doesn't mean that it is freely available (I think this is quite sad) or that each vendor is adhering to the standard to it's fullest (I can understand that). Still I've researched a bit and found an alternative to the IEEE standard worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth adding all STM32F0/1/2/3/4/7 have built in USART bootloaders.

Many of those chips have the ability to load over other interfaces than the USART, however the built-in USART bootloader is common to all of them.

ST Micro provide a program to use this, but it is Windows only. However, there is an Open Source Python program (stm32loader.py) which runs on most platforms, that will upload a binary over serial to an STM32. Apparently the [original](http://tuxotronic.org/wiki/projects/stm32loader) had a bug, however [Pete Harrison of micromouseonline](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2009/05/08/stm32-arm-cortex-bootloader/) has [fixed it](http://www.micromouseonline.com/files/arm/stm32loader.zip).

AFAICT the BeagleBone Black has about 5 UARTS, for example [Adafruit have a python library](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/uart) to use it.

Hence you can make a communication connection between a BeagleBone (black) (BBB) and almost any STM32F over the USART, and upload binary program files from the BBB to almost any STM32 using that Open Source 'stm32loader.py' Python program.

There are also instructions on using that program, which I have used successfully with an FTDI USB to serial cable, at [LeafLabs "Flashing the new Bootloader"](http://leaflabs.com/docs/bootloader.html). So it may be possible to also use that 'stm32loader.py' program with a USB-to-UART cable, with the BeagleBone (black) as the USB host.

It was relatively straightforward to find information using an internet search once the information from [micromouseonline](http://www.micromouseonline.com/2009/05/08/stm32-arm-cortex-bootloader/), [LeafLabs](http://leaflabs.com/docs/bootloader.html) or [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-io-python-library-on-beaglebone-black/uart) is found.

You could go down the SWD/JTAG route. For example the [Black Magic probe](http://www.blacksphere.co.nz/main/blackmagic) is a USB device, which does **not** need any drivers installed on the host. It directly implements GDBs protocols, and supports upload and full gdb debugging of STM32F. It is Open Source, and runs on an STM32F103. So, in theory, you could make one of these yourself.

LeafLabs released an Open Source STM32F103 bootloader, which enabled the STM32 to emulate a USB DFU device (i.e. it looked like the binary program upload device of a mobile phone). Their was also some efforts, reported on [Leaflabs Forum](http://forums.leaflabs.com/) on [this thread](http://forums.leaflabs.com/topic.php?id=9464#post-20859) and others where users had successfully used the built-in USB bootloader on the STM32F4, but I can't remember enough of the details.

The original LeafLabs STM32F103, USB DFU bootloader has been taken further by the folks at [stm32duino.com](http://www.stm32duino.com/), however, I am not yet familiar enough to know that it supports STM32F4.